# python - matching string and replacing

Tags: python

I have a file i am trying to replace parts of a line with another word.

it looks like bobkeiser:bob123@bobscarshop.com:0.0.0.0.0:23rh32o3hro2rh2:234212

i need to delete everything but bob123@bobscarshop.com, but i need to match 23rh32o3hro2rh2 with 23rh32o3hro2rh2:poniacvibe , from a different text file and place poniacvibe infront of bob123@bobscarshop.com

so it would look like this bob123@bobscarshop.com:poniacvibe

I've had a hard time trying to go about doing this, but i think i would have to split the bobkeiser:bob123@bobscarshop.com:0.0.0.0.0:23rh32o3hro2rh2:234212 with data.split(":") , but some of the lines have a (:) in a spot that i don't want the line to be split at, if that makes any sense...

if anyone could help i would really appreciate it.

Comment: Show an example line with a colon that isn't a delimiter, please. You will need a pattern that distinguishes between them, since a simple `.split(":")` can't be made to work.

Comment: cars:funkycars@gmail.com:11.111.111.111:8463ea7e4905996dggr53b789269dbc5a4:TDf , if the one i want to keep from this line is only the second one, would it matter? the only other place a colon could end up would be in the "8463ea7e4905996dggr53b789269dbc5a4" part

Answer (score 3):

ok, it looks to me like you are using a colon : to separate your strings.

in this case you can use .split(":") to break your strings into their component substrings

eg:

```
firststring = "bobkeiser:bob123@bobscarshop.com:0.0.0.0.0:23rh32o3hro2rh2:234212"
print(firststring.split(":"))
```

would give:

```
['bobkeiser', 'bob123@bobscarshop.com', '0.0.0.0.0', '23rh32o3hro2rh2', '234212']
```

and assuming your substrings will always be in the same order, and the same number of substrings in the main string you could then do:

```
firststring = "bobkeiser:bob123@bobscarshop.com:0.0.0.0.0:23rh32o3hro2rh2:234212"
firstdata = firststring.split(":")

secondstring = "23rh32o3hro2rh2:poniacvibe"
seconddata = secondstring.split(":")

if firstdata[3] == seconddata[0]:
    outputdata = firstdata
    outputdata.insert(1,seconddata[1])
    outputstring = ""
    for item in outputdata:
        if outputstring == "":
            outputstring = item
        else
            outputstring = outputstring + ":" + item
```

what this does is:

1. extract the bits of the strings into lists
2. see if the "23rh32o3hro2rh2" string can be found in the second list
3. find the corresponding part of the second list
4. create a list to contain the output data and put the first list into it
5. insert the "poniacvibe" string before "bob123@bobscarshop.com"
6. stitch the outputdata list back into a string using the colon as the separator

the reason your strings need to be the same length is because the index is being used to find the relevant strings rather than trying to use some form of string type matching (which gets much more complex)

if you can keep your data in this form it gets much simpler.

to protect against malformed data (lists too short) you can explicitly test for them before you start using len(list) to see how many elements are in it.

or you could let it run and catch the exception, however in this case you could end up with unintended results, as it may try to match the wrong elements from the list.

hope this helps

James

EDIT:
ok so if you are trying to match up a long list of strings from files you would probably want something along the lines of:

```
firstfile = open("firstfile.txt", mode = "r")
secondfile= open("secondfile.txt",mode = "r")

first_raw_data = firstfile.readlines()
firstfile.close()

second_raw_data = secondfile.readlines()
secondfile.close()

first_data = []
for item in first_raw_data:
    first_data.append(item.replace("\n","").split(":"))

second_data = []
for item in second_raw_data:
    second_data.append(item.replace("\n","").split(":"))

output_strings = []
for item in first_data:
    searchstring = item[3]
    for entry in second_data:
        if searchstring == entry[0]:
            output_data = item
            output_string = ""
            output_data.insert(1,entry[1])
            for data in output_data:
                if output_string == "":
                    output_string = data
                else:
                    output_string = output_string + ":" + data
            output_strings.append(output_string)
            break

for entry in output_strings:
    print(entry)
```

this should achieve what you're after and as prove of concept will print the resulting list of stings for you.

if you have any questions feel free to ask.

James

Second edit:
to make this output the results into a file change the last two lines to:

```
outputfile = open("outputfile.txt", mode = "w")
for entry in output_strings:
    outputfile.write(entry+"\n")
outputfile.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything is in a text file, so there are many many lines that look exactly like this carking:kingofcars@gmail.com::a32904184a82e3865dcc0335544644:_(i , then in another text file it has  a32904184a82e3865dcc0335544644:_(i:honda , so it would be the same concept? I would have to open the text files?

Comment: i have amended my answer to include that scenario

Comment: And why does it sayd IndentationErro: Expected an indented block

Comment: you need to check that when you are copying it that it indents correctly, i'm not sure why you had that problem as i copied it and pasted it without issues, but go through and check the indentation (if in doubt delete the indentation and manually put it back in again - in IDLE you can use the keyboard shortcuts ctrl+[ to de-dent and ctr;+] to indent)